# Concatenate or join text arrays based upon the cell value using if statement within vba for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA programming and am trying to add text to a cell based upon its value within an If Statement. I have tried using a find statement, but it ends in a null value and ultimately, I need this to work for 3 different values. I am not sure I need to define "MyCell" as a variable. It has not worked either way. When I run the code below it says MyCell is an invalid qualifier.

```
 Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro to insert Text into Cells

Dim i As Long
Dim MyCell As String

Worksheets("Tax").Active
For i = 2 To Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveCell.Select
    MyCell = ActiveCell.Value

        If MyCell.Value = "State Tax" Then
            MyCell = Join("State Tax - ", Range(i, "D"))

        ElseIf MyCell.Value = "SUI" Then
            MyCell = Join("SUI - ", Range(i, "D"))

        ElseIf MyCell.Value = "Local Tax" Then
            MyCell = Join("Local Tax - ", Range(i, "D"))
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show your input and desired output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need myCell.  If you did you would have instanced it as a range, not a string.  Try this and see if it accomplished what you need.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro to insert Text into Cells

Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Tax")
For i = 2 To .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("H" & i).Value = "State Tax" Then
             .Range("H" & i).Value = "State Tax - " & .Range("D" & i).Value

        ElseIf .Range("H" & i).Value = "SUI" Then
            .Range("H" & i).Value = "SUI - " & .Range("D" & i).Value

        ElseIf .Range("H" & i).Value = "Local Tax" Then
            .Range("H" & i).Value = "Local Tax - " & .Range("D" & i).Value
        End If

    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had been working on this for a while. I noticed you used "With Worksheets("Tax")" versus "Worksheets("Tax").Active". May you explain why? Also, I assume, I need to use range vs cells as the loop uses range?

Comment: It is much more efficient to not select or activate sheets.  You can do anything you want with a sheet without activating it or selecting a range in most cases.  The only thing to remember in coding "with worksheets(Sheet1)" method is to put a period in front of the range objects, so VBA knows you are talking about that worksheet and not the active one.  Would you please do me a favor and click the gray up-arrow to the left top of the answer to give me points?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It is quite helpful. I did give you points, although they do not appear publicly yet.